# Flush File Read Cache

Tags: c++, winapi

How do I flush (empty) the windows file read cache using C++ win32api?

Comment: Are you trying to measure some kind of cold-start performance?

Comment: Yes, right now I have to restart the computer every time... not very practical...

Comment: A Windows "file read cache" is mostly a figure of speech. There's no direct equivalent. Yes, there are a number of pages in RAM that correspond to files on disk, but those mappings could also exist because of memory-mapped files or paged in modules. Furthermore, a single page might be in RAM for multiple reasons. All those pages could be discarded from RAM; which specifically would you want to discard? You might end up evicting your own program from RAM.

Comment: Instead of restarting the entire computer, can you use removable media?  Disconnecting a USB drive would flush its read cache, you'll get cold-start performance when you plug it back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try DeviceIoControl with [IOCTL_DISK_SET_CACHE_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365187%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Why bother marking answers that aren't helpful?  Looks to me like Zach should get it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can (you could flush write cache), but you could always open your file via CreateFile with FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING. This way, your reads would not be from the system cache, but straight from your device (which may cache data).

Comment: I don't have access to the CreateFile call, I'm using a thirdparty library.

Comment: Then the library is not suitable for what you're trying to do. If you're simply trying to read a file to measure the performance of a drive, then it's really not that hard to use pure WinAPI.